# Is there a font size to screen size relation? iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, uitextview, swift3, font-size

I have a UITextView where I write line by line values from a csv.

typical lines

> the "|" represents the edge of screen

```
| name of place       timeAtPlace        |
| name of place       timeAtPlace        |
| longer name of place       timeAtPlace |
```

Text aligns to the left but I also want the timeAtPlace to align to the right. 
To achieve this

```
| name of place              timeAtPlace |
| name of place              timeAtPlace |
| longer name of place       timeAtPlace |
```

My thinking is to pad the string to the length of the line. To do that I need to know how many characters can fit on a line for the current device.

Is there a way to calculate this, is there any relation between fonts point size and devices point size? or is there any way to divide the screen (*I say screen but in this case mean the UITextView) size by font size to know how many characters can fit on the line?

Comment: can't you use `UILabel` ?

Comment: I can. Please elaborate on how that would help me?

Comment: you do not want truncating dots like `(example...)` at end right ?

Comment: No. I want to add spaces between the words on the left and the words on the right so that the left hand side words align left of screen and the right hand side words align to right of screen. If i can calculate how many characters fit per line I would be able to work out how many blank space characters " " I can append to each line

Comment: but why you not using two label instead?? use two separate labels!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `UILabel` as you mentioned in comment and you want to show text without truncating at right side alignment then you can do something like,

```
   UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 500, 100, 30)];  // your desired frame

label.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
[label setLineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByCharWrapping];

label.text = @"This is long string to test";

 [self.view addSubview:label];
```

Comment: Sure I could place the right hand text which is always same length in a UILabel then calculate that UILabels width and create a second UILabel to fit the remaining space of the screens width. Place the left had text in that UILabel and use adjustFontToFit. However I do not know how many lines are returned from the CSV file and if 100,000+ do not want to be adding UILabel instances that many times. A UITextField (I assume) will take up less memory that many UILabels. If not UITextField then I would be looking at a custom cell and a UITableview instead.